# How to grab last row of datetime in Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, group-by

II currently have a very large .csv with 2 million rows. I've read in the csv and only have 2 columns, number and timestamp (in unix). My goal is to grab the last and largest number for each day (eg. 1/1/2021, 1/2/2021, etc.)

[image]

I have converted unix to datetime and used df.groupby('timestamp').tail(1) but am still not able to return the last row per day. Am I using the groupby wrong?

[image]

```
import pandas as pd

def main():
    df = pd.read_csv('blocks.csv', usecols=['number', 'timestamp'])
    print(df.head())
    df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'],unit='s')
    x = df.groupby('timestamp').tail(1)
    print(x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Desired Output:

```
    number    timestamp
11,509,218   2021-01-01
11,629,315   2021-01-02
11,782,116   2021-01-03
12,321,123   2021-01-04
...
```

Comment: You don't assign the result of `df.groupby('timestamp').tail(1)` to anything. Try `x=df.groupby('timestamp').tail(1)` and then `print(x)`

Comment: Hi @AndrejKesely I've gone ahead and tried your suggestion. It still seems to have many rows with the same date. I have updated my post with the picture of the output if you take a look.

Comment: Try `x=df.groupby(df['timestamp'].dt.date).tail(1)`

Comment: Hi @AndrejKesely, Thank you that worked a charm. Could you post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: *Done.* I've posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *"problem"* lies in the grouper, use [`.dt.date`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.date.html) for correct grouping (assuming your data is already sorted):

```py
x = df.groupby(df['timestamp'].dt.date).tail(1)
print(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't seem like you're specifying the aggregation function, nor the aggregation frequency (hour, day, minute?)
My take would be something along the lines of

```
df.resample("D", on="timestamp").max()
```

There's a couple of ways to group by time, alternatively

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='timestamp', axis=0, 
                  freq='D', sort=True)).max()
```

Regards